# Sonar API call for incremental issues

Tags: api, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

Sonar API allows us to get the information from SonarQube DB.

We have made sonar API call to get the issues of all the sonarQube project in sonar Analysis. It has 1 Million issues for all the projects. We like to download all the issues from Sonar and place it in the DB as one time activity.

Then later keep get the issues (incremental/delta which has changes in the issues)  which is resolved need to be inserted into DB by making sonar API call.

1. How can we make the second call which filters by time stamp or updated after the inital load.
2. What is the best way to pull all the issues (1 million) ?
3. From our observation Sonar API taking approx 3 seconds to pull 500 issues in single page. Is there any way to make this lighter  ?

As of now we are using below api call for first initial load.
`https://devXXXXX.com/sonar/api/issues/search?severities=INFO&asc=true`
We included ps and p by runtime to navigate to each page to get all the 1 million records.

Please show some light to us on this API.

Comment: What API calls have you tried for this and how did they work or fail?

Comment: I have tried Sonar API search call for issues. All the project issue count becomes 1 million which was pulled with below query `https://devXXX.com/sonar/api/issues/search?severities=INFO&asc=true`. I can use ps and p in query string to navigate to the page. But i like to know how can I get incremental data once i loaded all the issues in background.

Comment: Perhaps you want to [edit] your question with those additional details? :-)

Comment: Yes. I have updated my question with more information. Please show some light on this ?

Answer (score 1):

1. > How can we make the second call which filters by time stamp or updated after the inital load.

   You can pull new issues using any of the following parameters: `createdAfter`, `createdAt`, `createdInLast`, but there are no parameters for distinguishing by updated date
2. > What is the best way to pull all the issues (1 million) ?

   From SonarQube 6.2 there is a hard limit on what you can retrieve from the web service: 10,000 issues. I.E. requesting `/api/issues/search?ps=500&p=21` will fail because that's simply not a supported use.
3. > From our observation Sonar API taking approx 3 seconds to pull 500 issues in single page. Is there any way to make this lighter ?

   For other web services, I'd tell you to use the `f` parameter to limit the field set retrieved for each record, but that parameter's not available on the issues search service. So no, there doesn't appear to be a way to speed this up.